# PLSQL Error : component must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

It is probably a lame error but I do not find it.
In a procedure I have this :

```
PROCEDURE myProcedure(returnCode OUT NUMBER) IS
CURSOR myCursor IS
  SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4 FROM MyTable WHERE columX IS NULL AND columnY = 'PS';

TYPE myType IS RECORD (
  name1 MyTable.Column1%TYPE,
  name2 MyTable.Column2%TYPE,
  name3 MyTable.Column3%TYPE,
  name4 MyTable.Column4%TYPE
);


myVar myType;
myVar2 typeA

BEGIN
   FOR myVar IN myCursor
   LOOP
      myVar2 := myVar.name2;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

ERROR :

```
PLS-00302 component name2 must be declared
```

What is wrong?

Ty

Comment: If you can say what it is you are trying to achieve then we can probably come up with the code that you need. As it stands it looks like you are missing quite a bit to complete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `myVar` cursor loop variable is not related to your `myVar` record-type variable; it's scope effectively overrides the type definition. You'd get the same error if you removed that type.

[From the documentation for cursor `for loop`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm):

> The cursor `FOR LOOP` statement implicitly declares its loop index as a record variable of the row type that a specified cursor returns.

and from [a related section](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS553):

> The cursor `FOR LOOP` statement implicitly declares its loop index as a `%ROWTYPE` record variable of the type that its cursor returns. This record is local to the loop and exists only during loop execution.

With this syntax, `myVar` is implicitly the same rowtype as the cursor itself, and has a `column2` field rather than a `name2` field; so this works:

```
BEGIN
   FOR myVar IN myCursor
   LOOP
      myVar2 := myVar.column2;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

and the both the `myVar` variable declaration and `myType` type declaration are redundant.

To use your record type instead you would need more explicit cursor handling:

```
BEGIN
   OPEN myCursor;
   LOOP
      FETCH myCursor INTO myVar;
      EXIT WHEN myCursor%NOTFOUND;
      myVar2 := myVar.name2;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE myCursor;
END;
```

Now `myVar` is still your `myType` record type variable - nothing is overriding that - so it has the field names you specified.

You could also explicitly define `myVar` as `myCursor%rowType` to avoid needing your own record type, but then it's just a longer way of writing the first loop, and you'd need to go back to referencing `myVar.column2`.